# visual basic 2010 nested loops

Tags: visual-studio-2010

hi good day to you all my name is hibari i'm currently working on the nested loop exercise and i cannot get over with this problem.....thank you in advance ,

'Clear the list
        ClearList()

```
    'process an outer loop
    For intOuterLoop As Integer = 1 To 5
        'process a nested (inner) loop
        For intInnerLoop As Integer 1 to 6
            lstData.Items.Add(intOuterLoop.ToString & ", " & intInnerLoop.ToString)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**every time i hit the debugging button i get an error(syntax error)**

Answer (score 0):

```
'process an outer loop
For intOuterLoop As Integer = 1 To 5
    'process a nested (inner) loop
    For intInnerLoop As Integer = 1 to 6
        lstData.Items.Add(intOuterLoop.ToString & ", " & intInnerLoop.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

End Sub